# Regex: Matching all words EXCEPT those inside of parenthesis (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, lookbehind

So given:

```
COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3, ((COLUMN_1) AS SOME TEXT) AS COLUMN_4, COLUMN_5
```

How would I go about getting my matches as:

```
COLUMN_1
COLUMN_2
COLUMN_3
COLUMN_4
COLUMN_5
```

I've tried:

```
(?<!(\(.*?\)))(\w+)(,\s*\w+)*?
```

But I feel like I'm way off base :(  I'm using regexstorm.net for testing.

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: What should be the result with `(COLUMN_1` or `COLUMN_1)` ?

Comment: If it's in parenthesis, it should be ignored :)  Thanks!

Comment: So `(COLUMN_1` / `COLUMN_1)` shouldn't be ignored?

Comment: (COLUMN_1 / COLUMN_1) would be ignored, as it is in parenthesis.

Comment: Why didn't you mention `AS` in expected output? I think it is a word outside parentheses too.

Comment: You are correct - ultimately, I don't want the As included, but that's easily parsed in a 2nd step.  It's this first parsing I'm having difficulty with.

Comment: Can you guarantee that parentheses will always be correctly balanced? You'll need a special regex construct called [balancing group definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) for this, and it only works if there are no nesting errors.

Comment: Yes, I actually validate for that very thing just prior to this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a regex that keeps track of opening and closing parentheses and makes sure that a word is only matched if a balanced set of parentheses (or no parentheses at all) follow:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"\w+                  # Match a word
    (?=                    # only if it's possible to match the following:
        (?>                # Atomic group (used to avoid catastrophic backtracking):
           [^()]+          # Match any characters except parens
        |                  # or
           \(  (?<DEPTH>)  # a (, increasing the depth counter
        |                  # or
           \)  (?<-DEPTH>) # a ), decreasing the depth counter
        )*                 # any number of times.
        (?(DEPTH)(?!))     # Then make sure the depth counter is zero again
        $                  # at the end of the string.
    )                      # (End of lookahead assertion)", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

I tried to  provide a test link to regexstorm.net, but it was too long for StackOverflow. Apparently, SO also doesn't like URL shorteners, so I can't link this directly, but you should be able to recreate the link easily: `http://bit[dot]ly/2cNZS0O`

Comment: Whew... alright, I'll study this for a bit, Tim.  Regex and I just don't get along so wonderfully - I start to think I've got a grasp on it, and it bites me again!  Appreciate the well-explained answer.

Comment: @John: I have just looked at regexstorm.net (didn't know it before); it seems you can't just click an "IgnorePatternWhitespace" checkbox there, but you can use the `(?x)` inline modifier. I've provided a test link in my answer now.

Comment: @John, you thank people by clicking the green checkmark to the left of their answer.

Comment: @Dour High Arch - thought I had, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've seen, I love you documenting every line to explain.  If I could give you extra points I would, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(?<!\()COLUMN_[\d](?!\))
```

Try it: https://regex101.com/r/bC4D7n/1

---

Update:

Ok, then try to use this regular expression:

```
[\(]+[\w\s\W]+[\)]+
```

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/bC4D7n/2

Comment: I just tried (?<!\()(\w+)(?!\)) - that's a little closer, but not quite.  COLUMN_x are just placeholders, btw, not the actual items I'm trying to regex :)

Comment: Ok, that gets JUST the stuff between the parenthesis (using regexstorm, I'm working with C# Regex).  I want to exclude that from the original, so I think this is SO VERY CLOSE lol!

Answer (score 1):

Matching all words *except some set of them* is one of the most difficult exercises you can do with regular expressions.  The easy way is: just construct the finite automata that accepts your original non negated predicate about the strings it should accept, then change all the accepting states by non-accepting ones, and finally construct a regular expression that is equivalent to the automata just constructed. This is a task difficult to do, so the most easy way to deal with it is **construct the regexp for the predicate you want to negate and pass your string through the regexp matcher, if it maches, just reject it**.

The main problem with this is that that is easy to do with computers, but constructing a regular expression from an automata description is tedious and normally gives you not the result you want (and actually a huge result).  Let me illustrate with an example:

You have asked for matching words, but from these words, you want the ones that don't appear in a set of them.  Let's suppose we want the automata that matches preciselly that set of words, and suppose we have matched the first `n-1` letters of that word.  This string should be matched, but only if you don't get the final letter next. So the proper regexp should be a regexp that matches all the letters of the first word but the last.... Not, we can skip this test if we have a word that matches all the letters in the first word but the last two, and so successively, back to the first letter (obviously, if your regexp doesn't begin with the first letter of the word, it doesn't match anyway)  Let's suppose the first word is `BEGIN`.  A good regexp matching things that are not equal to `BEGIN` is something like this:

```
[^B]|B[^E]|BE[^G]|BEG[^I]|BEGI[^N]
```

a different scenario (that complicates things more) is to find a regexp that matches the string if the word `BEGIN` is not contained in the string.  Let's part from the opposite predicate, to find a string that *has the word `BEGIN` included*

```
^.*BEGIN.*$
```

and let's construct its finite automata:

```
(0)---B--->(1)---E--->(2)---G--->(3)---I--->(4)---N--->((5))
 ^ \        |          |          |          |           ^ \
 | |        |          |          |          |           | |
 `-+<-------+<---------+<---------+<---------'           `-+
```

where the double parenthesis indicates an accepting state.  If you just
change all the accepting states with non-accepting ones, you'll get an automata that accepts all the strings the first one didn't and viceversa.

```
((0))--B-->((1))--E-->((2))--G-->((3))--I-->((4))--N-->(5)
 ^ \         |          |          |          |         ^ \
 | |         |          |          |          |         | |
 `-+<--------+<---------+<---------+<---------'         `-+
```

But converting this into a simple regular expression is far from easy (you can try, if you don't believe me)

And this only with one word, so think how to match any of the words, construct the automata, and then switch the acceptance-nonacceptance status of each state.

In your case, we have something to deal with, in addition to the premise your predicate is not equivalent to the one I have formulated.  My predicate is for matching expressions that have one word in it (which is the target for which regexp were conceived) but yours if *for matching groups inside your regexp*.  If you try my example, you will find that a simple string as `""` (the empty string) matches the second regexp, as the starting `((0))` state is accepting state (well, the empty string doesn't contain the word `BEGIN`), but you want your regexp to match words (and `""` isn't a word) so we first need to define what is a word for you and construct the regular expression that matches a word:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*
```

should be a good candidate. It should go in an automata definition like this:

```
(0)---[a-zA-Z]--->((1))---[a-zA-Z]--.
 ^ \               |  ^             |
 |  *              *  |             |
 `--+<-------------'  `-------------'
```

and you want an automata to accept both (1-must be a word, and 2-not in the set of words)  (not being in the set of words is the same as not being the first word, and not being the second and not being the third... you can construct it by first constructing an automata that matches if it's the first word, **or** the second, **or** the third, ... and then negating it)  construct the first automaton, the second and then construct an automaton that matches *both*.  This, again is easy to be done with automatons for computers, but not for people.

As I said, construct an automaton from a regexp is an easy and direct thing for a computer, but not for a person.  Construct a regexp from an automaton is also, but it results in huge regular expressions and because of this problem, most implementations have result in implementation of extender operators that match if some regexp doesn't and the opposite.

## CONCLUSION

Use the negation operators that allow you to get to the opposite predicate about the set of strings your regexp acceptor must accept, or just simply construct a regexp to do simple things and use the boolean algebra to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have nested parentheses things get trickier. Although .NET RegEx engine provides *balancing group constructs* which uses stack memory, I go with a more general approach called *recursive match*.

Regex:

```
\((?(?!\(|\)).|(?R))*\)|(\w+)
```

**[Live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/YZlTGp/1)**

All you need is in first capturing group.

Explanation of left side of alternation:

```
\(           # Match an opening bracket
(?(?!\(|\))  # If next character is not `(` or `)`
    .             # Then match it
    |             # Otherwise
    (?R)          # Recurs whole pattern
)*           # As much as possible
\)           # Up to corresponding closing bracket
```

Comment: Revo, when I try that using regexstorm.net, I get Unrecognized grouping construct :(

Comment: .NET regexes don't support recursion, only balancing groups.

Comment: Sorry I thought recursions are available in .NET, they are not. @John